# How to search and add a string before the pattern in python using regular expressions

Tags: regex, string, python-3.x

Iam writing a program to find and replace a string from all the files with the given extension.
Here Iam using regular expressions for searching.The task is to findall the occurances and modify those.

> If my string is "The number is 1234567890"
>   Result after searching and replacing should be +911234567890

I think i can re.sub() here like

```
s = "The number is 1234567890"
re.sub(r"\d{10}",??,s)
```

What can be given as the second argument here i don't know what the number would be i have modify the same matched string by preceding it with +91

I could do it using the findall from re and replace from string like

```
s = "The number is 1234567890 and 2345678901"
matches = re.findall(r'\d{10}',s)
for match in matches:
    s = s.replace(match,"+91"+match)
```

> After this s is The number is +911234567890 and +912345678901

Is this the only way of doing it??Is it not possible using re.sub() ??
If it is please help me.Thank you...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(?=\d{10})
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/K3U915/1/)**

**Explanation:**

- `(?=\d{10})` - positive lookahead to find a zero-length match which is immediately followed by 10 digits

**Code**

```
import re
regex = r"(?=\d{10})"
test_str = "The number is 1234567890"
subst = "+91"
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0)
if result:
    print (result)
```

[**Code Output**](http://rextester.com/ISFA3804)

**OR**

If I use **[your regex](https://regex101.com/r/K3U915/2/)**, the code would look like:

```
import re
regex = r"(\d{10})"
test_str = "The number is 1234567890"
subst = "+91$1"
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0)
if result:
    print (result)
```

Comment: What does $1 do??

Comment: $1 contains the contents of Group 1 which, in this case, is the 10 digit number.

Comment: Can you tell me resource for learning about positive lookahead.

Comment: [THIS](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is a good website to begin with

Comment: Thank you for helping :)